# TeXmaker is stuck on "Process Started" - process hangs

Tags: xetex, compiling

When I run my script in Texmaker, the program displays the message "Process started" and just hangs there.

[image]

A previous version of the same file ran with no issues in the past, only now that I made a few minor edits to the content did I start running into this issue. Important to note: I tried compiling those previously successful scripts, and now those won't run either!

This is my compile sequence: xelatex > biber > xelatex > view pdf

[image: Commands configuration]

[image: Quick Build configuration]

I have tried:

1. Deleting the .log file from the working directory - same result.
2. Running only a PdfLaTeX build, I get an error: Package fontspec needs XeLaTeX to compile.
3. Running previous files that had worked in the past, outcome: Process hangs > I stop the process > No error messages generate (file does not compile).

ANY help would be greatly appreciated.
-Manny

Comment: Can you compile a simple "hello world" file?

Comment: try to compile a small file in a terminal and not in texmaker to get a better error message.

Comment: @user202729 - Yes I can!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I tried compiling this in Texmaker:

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}

... and it worked!

Comment: Still no luck with the original file, though.

Comment: Then the problem is likely with your file. Create a minimal working example.

Comment: Thanks! I updated Texmaker, then went back to an original file, compiled - successfully (!), then edited the file, and compiled - successfully again! I don't know if the old version of Texmaker was the cause, but I suppose having the latest version didn't hurt it either. Thanks again for the help!